# How can i create a Distribution profisional profile for my app?

Tags: ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program

I got approval from apple for my ios program enrollment,so iam going to put my app in app store.But when i tried to create a "Distribution profile" it showing that "i should create a certificate before creating profile" . How can i create a new certificate??

Please help

[image]

Please tell me how can i create new certificate step by step

Answer (score 2):

You have to create it in your keychain access.

Ray Wenderlich will become your guru :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Launchpad-> utilities ->keyChain Acess

[image]

now select

Request a certificate from a Certificate Authority "

fill necessary information save it on desktop